LZ4 deprecated function being called within a deprecated function inside implementation
In LZ4 compression library in a header file we have a function definition which is deprecated:
/*! Obsolete decompression functions (since v1.8.0) */
LZ4_DEPRECATED("use LZ4_decompress_fast() instead") LZ4LIB_API int LZ4_uncompress (const char* source, char* dest, int outputSize);

So I won't get a deprecated compiler warning unless I call that function, right? However in a .c file there is the definition for that deprecated function, which calls LZ4_decompress_fast(), which is deprecated itself. So there's no way of compiling this, right?
// In .c file, this is a deprecated function
int LZ4_uncompress (const char* source, char* dest, int outputSize)
{
    return LZ4_decompress_fast(source, dest, outputSize); // But so is this
}

Hence a deprecated function is being called within the .c file, and it's impossible to compile. Does this make sense? How could this issue have slipped the author? It's impossible, I must be doing something wrong. It's just two files:
The header
And the .c file
I'm compiling on Visual Studio and the error I get is:

Error C4996   'LZ4_decompress_fast': This function is deprecated and
unsafe. Consider using LZ4_decompress_safe_partial() instead

Because the functions are marked:
__declspec(deprecated(message))


and it's impossible to compile. Why is it impossible to compile?

The compiler does not analyse whether or not you call the deprecated function. It reports when the deprecated definition is compiled.

Have you tried compiling it?  What result did you get?

Also, it appears not to be LZ4_decompress_fast that is deprecated, but LZ4_uncompress. So they want you to call LZ4_decompress_fast directly instead of LZ4_uncompress, even though it too calls the former.

@500-InternalServerError LZ4_decompress_fast is deprecated too, it's marked deprecated in the header.

@WeatherVane Your statement seems to be wrong, the compiler gives that deprecated warning preventing me from compiling if the function is called. If the call to LZ4_decompress_fast is commented out I don't get that error.

Deprecation is a warning, and warnings are not errors unless you explicitly state so.

The edit to the question seems to be the answer. There was a deprecation chain, and hopefully you've reached the end of it.

@dbush Well I get an error because that function has been marked (in my case in Visual Studio) with __declspec(deprecated(message))

The deprecation markings seem to be sub-optimal, in that you need to follow one unneressary step to locate the non-deprecated function. Consider filing a ticket, preferably with a patch or pull request.

@UlrichEckhardt This is LZ4, very famous, everyone uses it, that's strange. Especially the HC version, supposedly great compression ratio and decompression rates up to 4000-5000 MB/s

I don't understand what you're trying to tell me with that. The fact that it's widely used is irrelevant. The header contents are not formally wrong, they're just slightly inconvenient.

The functions were probably deprecated at different times. When LZ4_decompress was deprecated, LZ4_decompress_fast was still OK. When they later deprecated LZ4_decompress_fast they didn't bother to find the deprecated function upstream from it, so they could fix its warning.

Unless you compile with -Werror, warnings should not prevent compiling. Errors prevent compilation, warnings normally don't.

They were replaced by LZ4_decompess_safe (the addon is blatant lie though, just like other _s functions) but you have to try -Werror flag only when you fight windmills... er, eradicate these 98765 warning in your code.

@Swift-FridayPie which is precisely why I always compile with -Werror or /WX, starting from the very beginning of each project. So yeah, third-party code that gets compiled on my side can be an annoyance... luckily, when I actively compile it myself (rather then something like vcpkg compiling it with its own options), I've usually copied it into my repository as well, so I'm also able to apply fixes... I just want to keep local changes to a minimum and automate them, to make updates easier.
